# JS works in one place but not another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm stumped on something that is a little odd. I was tinkering with some code in an html file that had js and html on it until I got it to work like I wanted then I copied and pasted it to the php file that is linked to a JS page. The trouble is that in the php page I get the error message unrecognized expression: select[name=gateHeight] option: selected. If anyone could explain what I messed up I would appreciate it very much!
Here is the html file with JS and HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
                newElem.children($("select[name=gateHeight] option: selected")).attr('id', 'gateHeight' + newNum).attr('name', 'gateHeight' + newNum);
                //newElem.children('input[type=text]:first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                newElem.children('input[type=checkbox]:first').attr('id', 'chk' + newNum).attr('name', 'chk' + newNum);

                // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

                // enable the "remove" button
                //$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');

                // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#input' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

                // enable the "add" button
                //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled');

                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="myForm">
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
       <!-- <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" /> -->
        <select name="gateHeight" id="gateHeight">
                            <option value="select">Select Gate Height</option>
                            <option value="4fg">4 Ft. Gate</option>
                            <option value="6fg">6 Ft. Gate</option>
                            <option value="8fg">8 Ft. Gate</option>
        </select> 
        Include Spring Pool Latch: <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

And here is the JS and HTML of the other file:
JS:

```
//Dynamic Gate Input Fields
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
                newElem.children($("select[name=gateHeight] option: selected")).attr('id', 'gateHeight' + newNum).attr('name', 'gateHeight' + newNum);
                //newElem.children('input[type=text]:first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                newElem.children('input[type=checkbox]:first').attr('id', 'chk' + newNum).attr('name', 'chk' + newNum);

                // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

                // enable the "remove" button
                //$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');

                // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#input' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

                // enable the "add" button
                //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled');

                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
                        <select name="gateHeight" id="gateHeight">
                                <option value="select">Select Gate Height</option>
                                <option value="4fg">4 Ft. Gate</option>
                                <option value="6fg">6 Ft. Gate</option>
                                <option value="8fg">8 Ft. Gate</option>
                        </select> 
                        Include Spring Pool Latch: <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" />
                    </div>

            <div>
                <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Another Gate" />
                <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove Gate" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$("select[name=gateHeight] option :selected")
```

`:selected`  is the right one not `: selected`  (no space)

OR

```
$("select[name=gateHeight] option").filter(":selected")
```

This will work

Comment: Y'all are some freaking geniuses. Lol. I still don't get why it worked in one file but not the other but oh well!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the document ready wrapper function your code is called before the element exist therefore fail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the space after the colon in `option: selected`. Just change that to `option:selected`.

Comment: Y'all are some freaking geniuses. Lol. I still don't get why it worked in one file but not the other but oh well!

Answer (score 1):

**First** you should use the `updated version` of `jquery` like **jquery-1.9** or higher.

**Second** you should use `newElem.children("select[name=gateHeight]")` in place of
    `newElem.children($("select[name=gateHeight] option: selected"))`
    like

```
newElem.find("select[name='gateHeight']")
           .attr({'id': 'gateHeight'+newNum, 'name': 'gateHeight' + newNum});// combine attr() using json
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RLrS5/)